# Use html tags in shortcode_atts, is it real?

Tags: php, shortcode

can i use html tags in shortcode attributes? like this:

```
function b_text( $atts, $content = null ) {
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'text' => '<div class="myClass">DOM</div>'
  ), $atts ) );
  ob_start();
?> 

  <div>
    <div> <?php echo $text; ?></div>
  </div>

<?php 
  $content = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $content;
}

add_shortcode('b-text', 'b_text');
```

Probably i can use some actions or filters to redefine my html content in atts? it is at all possible? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is a technically possibility, it's most likely direction that isn't worth it.

Overuse of shortcodes for what is essentially (crappy) templating is problematic and has a history of security issues.

In recent months there has been [ongoing planning and discussion](https://make.wordpress.org/core/tag/shortcodes/) about possibility of changes to shortocde syntax and mechanics in core. HTML in attributes is explicitly named as one of the problems that led to it.